# What is the meaning of window size logarithm in zlib library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib

> The wbits argument controls the size of the history buffer (or the “window size”) used when compressing
>   data, and whether a header and trailer is included in the output. It can take several ranges of values,
>   defaulting to 15 (MAX_WBITS):"
>
> The wbits argument controls the size of the history buffer (or the “window size”) used when compressing
>   data, and whether a header and trailer is included in the output. It can take several ranges of values,
>   defaulting to 15 (MAX_WBITS):
>
> • +9 to +15: The """""""'BASE-TWO LOGARITHM OF THE WINDOW SIZE'""""", which therefore ranges between 512 and
>   32768. Larger values produce better compression at the expense of greater memory usage. The
>   resulting output will include a zlib-specific header and trailer.

link: [zlib in py documentary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html)

zlib.compressobj(level=-1, method=DEFLATED, wbits=MAX_WBITS, memLevel=DEF_MEM_LEVEL, strategy=Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY[, zdict
])

This term used definition of WBITS

I couldn't understand Window size logarithm mean in documentary..What does it mean in compression?And why used even.?

Comment: where are you getting the word logarithm?

Comment: add a link to the doc and specify the usage that you don't understand... the question is a little bit confusing...

Comment: Guys I have update post.Even my question is at the bottom on post.

Comment: 9 is the base-2 logarithm of 512 (because 2⁹ = 512), and likewise 15 is the base-2 logarithm of 32768.  The window size parameter is being represented as a logarithm rather than the actual size, because this is more compact (4 vs. 16 bits), and can't represent non-power-of-2 sizes (which aren't valid).

Answer (score 1):

Window size may refer to how large a chunk of data the compression algorithm will look at for self-similar data it can compress. Larger windows of data require more ram usage, but will result in better compressed data (depending on the data you are compressing it may or may not matter. Testing with different C-values might help find a good middle-ground between time for the data to compress, and output file size.) Different low-power hardware might 
benefit from smaller windows.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html

This link was helpful. python 2 vs 3 shouldn't matter for the window size.

Comment: "Larger windows of data require more ram usage" -So i thing here windows mean like thread.Cause uses ram usage.Or you mean windows a chunk of data to be compressed?